# Prevent Elasticsearch from splitting on specific character while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field with values such as `170726-001`, `170726-002`, `170726-003` and it appears that the values in the three fields get split into `170726` and `00N`.  This affects the relevance of my search results when searching for `170726-001` as a keyword using Query String Query.

How to I prevent Elasticsearch from splitting the value on the `-` character when indexing?

Comment: use the `keyword` type instead of `text` or add a `keyword` sub-field to your existing `text` field

Comment: You can also search the .raw of the field to search only for the original.

Comment: I think you should look into [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping) in elasticsearch

Comment: @filip-cordas - I agree its probably a mapping change I can make, I'm just not sure how

Comment: Unfortunately mapping changes usually require re-indexing of everything  but as 2.0 elasticsearch you get the "keyword" sub field so you can probably use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @filip-cordas and other comments I updated my index to reflect the following.  Its using the `keyword` type instead of the default `text` type.  Doing it on index like this prevents me from having to specify my_field.keyword in the search.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```